# Can't open working VIM editor from Java/Scala console application

Tags: java, python, scala, shell, vim

I'm trying to run an interactive editor from a Java command-line program. As an example, this is the equivalent code in Python:

```
import subprocess; subprocess.call(["vim", "/tmp/hello"])
```

And it opens up a vim editor and returns control to the Python program when you're done editing.

The "equivalent" Java program:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
        new java.lang.ProcessBuilder()
                .command("vim", "/tmp/hello2")
                .inheritIO()
                .start();

    }
}
```

Does not open up VIM properly and leaves my terminal in a funky state that I need to call `reset` before continuing.

The "equivalent" Scala program

```
object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import sys.process._
    Seq("vim", "/tmp/hello2").!<
  }
}
```

Opens up VIM successfully, but keyboard navigation is borked, and pressing the arrow keys results in input like

```
^[OD^[OA^[OC^[OB
```

being entered into the text area instead of moving my cursor around.

Is there some way to replicate the correct Python behavior in Java/Scala?

Answer (score 1):

Programs such `vi, emacs` work in terminal programs such as `xterm`. They are not designed to work in process streams which is what `Java` and `Scala` use to execute external programs using `ProcessBuilder` and `sys.process` respectively. This is why you are not able to manipulate the cursor successfully and why `vim` does not open up properly forcing you to reset.

I haven't tried this but you could try invoking a terminal program instead of `vim` directly and passing an argument to that terminal program to open up `vim`.